# Замена определенного тега (regexp)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте.

Есть такой код:

```
$string = "<tag>test";
$string = preg_replace("/(\<xml\>)/", " ", $string);
echo $string;
```

Но, заменяет любой тег, находящийся в <>. Необходимо чтобы он заменял тег `<xml и его содержимое>`

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "<xml params='10' log=10><tag>test <xml> test <xml params='10'>";
$string = preg_replace("/(\<xml.*?\>)/", " ", $string);

echo htmlspecialchars($string);
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b68-qvu

Comment: 1. Экранировать знаки "<" и ">" не нужно.

2. Вместо точки лучше поставить конструкцию `[^>]`, иначе при жадном поиске будут проблемы